# How to use paths_allowed?

Tags: r, rvest

What's wrong with my code?
Here is my code:

```r
paths_allowed("https://collections.ed.ac.uk/art)")
```

Here is the error message:

> Error in paths_allowed("https://collections.ed.ac.uk/art)") :
> could not find function "paths_allowed"

Comment: try to launch `library( robotstxt )` before calling the function

Comment: it says "there is no package called robotstxt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paths_allowed` is a function of the package `robotstxt`.

To use the function, you need to install the package first.
Then, after loading the package with `library`, you will be able to use your function.

```
install.packages("robotstxt")
library(robotstxt)
paths_allowed("https://collections.ed.ac.uk/art)")
```

If you don't want to load the package you can alternatively call the function with `::` operator in this way:

```
robotstxt::paths_allowed("https://collections.ed.ac.uk/art)")
```

Comment: may want to note that the package only needs to be installed once per R installation (unlike `library()`, which needs to be called in each new R session)